# How to debug windows store app on tablet?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, remote-debugging, powershell-remoting

How to debug windows store app on tablet through Remote machine? 
I tried debugging through remote debugging but unable to connect with device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the properties of the UI project, you can give the IP address of the device to be connected.

This link might help you - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441469.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the solution,
how can i get Windows App certification kit for my tablet??